# tensorflow stop optimizing when activation step is in a function

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm trying to reproduce the result of https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/mnist/beginners/

So I designed several functions to take care of the training step such as these two:

```
def layer_computation(previous_layer_output, weights, bias, activation):
    return activation(tf.add(tf.matmul(previous_layer_output, weights), bias))

def multilayer_perceptron_forward(x, weights, biaises, activations):
    return reduce(lambda output_layer, args: layer_computation(output_layer, *args),
              zip(weights, biaises, activations), x)
```

By using these two functions for the training

```
def training(session,
         features, labels,
         mlp,
         # cost = (tf.reduce_mean, ),
         optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer,
         epochs=100, learning_rate=0.001, display=100):

x = tf.placeholder("float")
y = tf.placeholder("float")
weights, biases, activations = mlp
pred = multilayer_perceptron_forward(x, weights, biases, activations)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=y))
opti = optimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
session.run(init)
for i in range(1, epochs + 1):
    batch_size = 100
    avg_cost = 0
    number_of_bacth = int(features.shape[0]/batch_size)
    for j in range(number_of_bacth):
        my_x = features[j*100:(j+1)*100, :]
        my_y = labels[j*100:(j+1)*100, :]
        _, c = session.run([opti, cost], feed_dict={x: my_x,
                                                    y: my_y})
        avg_cost += c/number_of_bacth

    if i % display == 0:
        print("Epoch {i} cost = {cost}".format(i=i, cost=avg_cost))
```

The optimization stops at a cost of 2.3... and the overall accuracy is of 10% whereas in the example it get closer to zero and the accuracy is close to 96%. Does anyone have an explanation for this peculiar behavior?

PS when I'm using *layer_computation* in the source code in the example I also get stuck at a cost of 2.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I caught the error, I was trying to perform back-propagation on the last layer. This question may have been better on cross-validated.

Comment: Welcome to SO: It would be better if you could post and explain the working solution for others who might come across this in their own search.